# Can MATLAB C generation coder generate C-code that fits embedded system?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, code-generation, matlab-coder

I need to convert this code into C code.

**Questions:**

1. Will MATLAB Coder generate C code that are memory safe, e.g they not using **calloc** or **malloc**. Misra C standard does not allow coder to use dynamical memory allocation. It's dangerous for embedded system due to memory leaks.
2. Will MATLAB Coder generate C code with dynamical matrix as argument e.g. functions with arguments **foo(float* A, int m, int n)** or **foo(int m, int n, float A[m][n])** or is fix size example **foo(float A[3][5])**, only available as option?
3. Will MATLAB Coder generate C code that can be fitted into an embedded system. How about the internal C++ commands in the .m files such as **horzcat**, **size** and **vertcat**? Will they become 100% portable C-code?
4. Will MATLAB Coder generate functions that have call by reference? Example **foo(float* input, float* output)** instead of **float* output = foo(float* input)**

   ```
   function [U] = mpc (A, B, C, x, N, r, lb)

     ## Find matrix
     PHI = phiMat(A, C, N);
     GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N);


     ## Solve first with no constraints
     U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, 0, 0, false);

     ## Then use the last U as upper bound
     U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, lb, U(end), true);

   end

   function U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, lb, ub, constraints)
     ## Set U
     U = zeros(N, 1);

     ## Iterate Gaussian Elimination
     for i = 1:N

       ## Solve u
       if(i == 1)
         u = (r - PHI(i,:)*x)/GAMMA(i,i)
       else
         u = (r - PHI(i,:)*x - GAMMA(i,1:i-1)*U(1:i-1) )/GAMMA(i,i)
       end

       ## Constraints 
       if(constraints == true)
         if(u > ub)
           u = ub;
         elseif(u < lb)
           u = lb;
         end
       end

       ## Save u
       U(i) = u
     end
   end

   function PHI = phiMat(A, C, N)

     ## Create the special Observabillity matrix
     PHI = [];
     for i = 1:N
       PHI = vertcat(PHI, C*A^i);
     end

   end

   function GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N)

     ## Create the lower triangular toeplitz matrix
     GAMMA = [];
     for i = 1:N
       GAMMA = horzcat(GAMMA, vertcat(zeros((i-1)*size(C*A*B, 1), size(C*A*B, 2)),cabMat(A, B, C, N-i+1)));
     end

   end

   function CAB = cabMat(A, B, C, N)

     ## Create the column for the GAMMA matrix
     CAB = [];
     for i = 0:N-1
       CAB = vertcat(CAB, C*A^i*B);
     end

   end
   ```

My C-code. Yes its working!

```
/*
 * Generalized_Predictive_Control.c
 *
 *  Created on: 
 *      Author:
 */

#include "Generalized_Predictive_Control.h"

/*
 * Parameters
 */
int adim;
int ydim;
int rdim;
int horizon;

/*
 * Deceleration
 */
static void obsv(float* PHI, const float* A, const float* C);
static void kalman(float* x, const float* A, const float* B, float* u, const float* K, float* y, const float* C);
static void mul(float* A, float* B, float* C, int row_a, int column_a, int column_b);
static void tran(float* A, int row, int column);
static void CAB(float* GAMMA, float* PHI, const float* A, const float* B, const float* C);
static void solve(float* GAMMA, float* PHI, float* x, float* u, float* r, float lb, float ub, int constraintsON);
static void print(float* A, int row, int column);


void GPC(int adim_, int ydim_, int rdim_, int horizon_, const float* A, const float* B, const float* C, const float* D, const float* K, float* u, float* r, float* y, float* x){
    /*
     * Set the dimensions
     */
    adim = adim_;
    ydim = ydim_;
    rdim = rdim_;
    horizon = horizon_;

    /*
     * Identify the model - Extended Least Square
     */
    int n = 5;
    float* phi;
    float* theta;
    //els(phi, theta, n, y, u, P);

    /*
     * Create a state space model with Observable canonical form
     */


    /*
     * Create the extended observability matrix
     */
    float PHI[horizon*ydim*adim];
    memset(PHI, 0, horizon*ydim*adim*sizeof(float));
    obsv(PHI, A, C);

    /*
     * Create the lower triangular toeplitz matrix
     */
    float GAMMA[horizon*rdim*horizon*ydim];
    memset(GAMMA, 0, horizon*rdim*horizon*ydim*sizeof(float));
    CAB(GAMMA, PHI, A, B, C);

    /*
     * Solve the best input value
     */
    solve(GAMMA, PHI, x, u, r, 0, 0, 0);
    solve(GAMMA, PHI, x, u, r, 0, *(u), 1);

    /*
     * Estimate the state vector
     */
    kalman(x, A, B, u, K, y, C);
}

/*
 * Identify the model
 */
static void els(float* P, float* phi, float* theta, int polyLength, int totalPolyLength, float* y, float* u, float* e){

    /*
     * move phi with the inputs, outputs, errors one step to right
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < polyLength; i++){
        *(phi + i+1 + totalPolyLength*0) = *(phi + i + totalPolyLength*0); // Move one to right for the y's
        *(phi + i+1 + totalPolyLength*1) = *(phi + i + totalPolyLength*1); // Move one to right for the u's
        *(phi + i+1 + totalPolyLength*2) = *(phi + i + totalPolyLength*2); // Move one to right for the e's
    }

    /*
     * Add the current y, u and e

    (*phi + totalPolyLength*0) = -*(y + 0); // Need to be negative!
    (*phi + totalPolyLength*1) =  *(u + 0);
    (*phi + totalPolyLength*2) =  *(e + 0);
 */
    /*
     * phi'*theta
     */
    float y_est = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < totalPolyLength; i++){
        y_est += *(phi + i) * *(theta + i);
    }
    float epsilon = *(y + 0) - y_est; // In this case, y is only one element array

    /*
     * phi*epsilon
     */
    float phi_epsilon[totalPolyLength];
    memset(phi_epsilon, 0, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < totalPolyLength; i++){
        *(phi_epsilon + i) = *(phi + i) * epsilon;
    }

    /*
     * P_vec = P*phi_epsilon
     */
    float P_vec[totalPolyLength];
    memset(P_vec, 0, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    mul(P, phi_epsilon, P_vec, totalPolyLength, totalPolyLength, 1);

    /*
     * Update our estimated vector theta = theta + P_vec
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < totalPolyLength; i++){
        *(theta + i) = *(theta + i) + *(P_vec + i);
    }

    /*
     * Update P = P - (P*phi*phi'*P)/(1 + phi'*P*phi)
     */
    // Create phi'
    float phiT[totalPolyLength];
    memset(phiT, 0, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    memcpy(phiT, phi, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    tran(phiT, totalPolyLength, 1);

    // phi'*P
    float phiT_P[totalPolyLength];
    memset(phiT_P, 0, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    mul(phiT, P, phiT_P, 1, totalPolyLength, totalPolyLength);

    // phi*phi'*P
    float phi_phiT_P[totalPolyLength*totalPolyLength];
    memset(phi_phiT_P, 0, totalPolyLength*totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    mul(phi, phiT_P, phi_phiT_P, totalPolyLength, 1, totalPolyLength);

    // P*phi*phi'*P
    float P_phi_phiT_P[totalPolyLength*totalPolyLength];
    memset(P_phi_phiT_P, 0, totalPolyLength*totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    mul(P, phi_phiT_P, P_phi_phiT_P, totalPolyLength, totalPolyLength, totalPolyLength);

    // P*phi
    float P_phi[totalPolyLength];
    memset(P_phi, 0, totalPolyLength*sizeof(float));
    mul(P, phi, P_phi, totalPolyLength, totalPolyLength, 1);

    // phi'*P*phi
    float phiT_P_phi[1];
    memset(phiT_P_phi, 0, 1*sizeof(float));
    mul(phiT, P_phi, phiT_P_phi, 1, totalPolyLength, 1);

    // P = P - (P_phi_phiT_P) / (1+phi'*P*phi)
    for(int i = 0; i < totalPolyLength*totalPolyLength; i++){
        *(P + i) = *(P + i) - *(P_phi_phiT_P + i) / (1 + *(phiT_P_phi));
    }

}

/*
 * This will solve if GAMMA is square!
 */
static void solve(float* GAMMA, float* PHI, float* x, float* u, float* r, float lb, float ub, int constraintsON){
    /*
     * Now we are going to solve on the form
     * Ax=b, where b = (R*r-PHI*x) and A = GAMMA and x = U
     */

    /*
     * R_vec = R*r
     */
    float R_vec[horizon*ydim];
    memset(R_vec, 0, horizon*ydim*sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < horizon*ydim; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < rdim; j++) {
            *(R_vec + i + j) = *(r + j);
        }
        i += rdim-1;
    }

    /*
     * PHI_vec = PHI*x
     */
    float PHI_vec[horizon*ydim];
    memset(PHI_vec, 0, horizon * ydim * sizeof(float));
    mul(PHI, x, PHI_vec, horizon*ydim, adim, 1);

    /*
     * Solve now (R_vec - PHI_vec) = GAMMA*U
     * Notice that this is ONLY for Square GAMMA with lower triangular toeplitz matrix e.g SISO case
     * This using Gaussian Elimination backward substitution
     */
    float U[horizon];
    float sum = 0.0;
    memset(U, 0, horizon*sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < horizon; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            sum += *(GAMMA + i*horizon + j) * *(U + j);
        }
        float newU = (*(R_vec + i) - *(PHI_vec + i) - sum) / (*(GAMMA + i*horizon + i));
        if(constraintsON == 1){
            if(newU > ub)
                newU = ub;
            if(newU < lb)
                newU = lb;
        }
        *(U + i) = newU;
        sum = 0.0;
    }
    //print(U, horizon, 1);

    /*
     * Set last U to u
     */
    if(constraintsON == 0){
        *(u + 0) = *(U + horizon - 1);
    }else{
        *(u + 0) = *(U + 0);
    }


}

/*
 * Lower traingular toeplitz of extended observability matrix
 */
static void CAB(float* GAMMA, float* PHI, const float* A, const float* B, const float* C){
    /*
     * First create the initial C*A^0*B == C*I*B == C*B
     */
    float CB[ydim*rdim];
    memset(CB, 0, ydim*rdim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*)C, (float*)B, CB, ydim, adim, rdim);

    /*
     * Take the transpose of CB so it will have dimension rdim*ydim instead
     */
    tran(CB, ydim, rdim);

    /*
     * Create the CAB matrix from PHI*B
     */
    float PHIB[horizon*ydim*rdim];
    mul(PHI, (float*) B, PHIB, horizon*ydim, adim, rdim); // CAB = PHI*B
    tran(PHIB, horizon*ydim, rdim);

    /*
     * We insert GAMMA = [CB PHI;
     *                    0  CB PHI;
     *                    0   0  CB PHI;
     *                    0   0   0  CB PHI] from left to right
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < horizon; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < rdim; j++) {
            memcpy(GAMMA + horizon*ydim*(i*rdim+j) + ydim*i, CB + ydim*j, ydim*sizeof(float)); // Add CB
            memcpy(GAMMA + horizon*ydim*(i*rdim+j) + ydim*i + ydim, PHIB + horizon*ydim*j, (horizon-i-1)*ydim*sizeof(float)); // Add PHI*B
        }
    }
    /*
     * Transpose of gamma
     */
    tran(GAMMA, horizon*rdim, horizon*ydim);
    //print(CB, rdim, ydim);
    //print(PHIB, rdim, horizon*ydim);
    //print(GAMMA, horizon*ydim, horizon*rdim);
}

/*
 * Transpose
 */
static void tran(float* A, int row, int column) {

    float B[row*column];
    float* transpose;
    float* ptr_A = A;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        transpose = &B[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            *transpose = *ptr_A;
            ptr_A++;
            transpose += row;
        }
    }

    // Copy!
    memcpy(A, B, row*column*sizeof(float));

}

/*
 * [C*A^1; C*A^2; C*A^3; ... ; C*A^horizon] % Extended observability matrix
 */
static void obsv(float* PHI, const float* A, const float* C){

    /*
     * This matrix will A^(i+1) all the time
     */
    float A_pow[adim*adim];
    memset(A_pow, 0, adim * adim * sizeof(float));
    float A_copy[adim*adim];
    memcpy(A_copy, (float*) A, adim * adim * sizeof(float));

    /*
     * Temporary matrix
     */
    float T[ydim*adim];
    memset(T, 0, ydim * adim * sizeof(float));

    /*
     * Regular T = C*A^(1+i)
     */
    mul((float*) C, (float*) A, T, ydim, adim, adim);

    /*
     * Insert temporary T into PHI
     */
    memcpy(PHI, T, ydim*adim*sizeof(float));

    /*
     * Do the rest C*A^(i+1) because we have already done i = 0
     */
    for(int i = 1; i < horizon; i++){
        mul((float*) A, A_copy, A_pow, adim, adim, adim); //  Matrix power A_pow = A*A_copy
        mul((float*) C, A_pow, T, ydim, adim, adim); // T = C*A^(1+i)
        memcpy(PHI + i*ydim*adim, T, ydim*adim*sizeof(float)); // Insert temporary T into PHI
        memcpy(A_copy, A_pow, adim * adim * sizeof(float)); // A_copy <- A_pow
    }
}

/*
 *   x = Ax - KCx + Bu + Ky % Kalman filter
 */
static void kalman(float* x, const float* A, const float* B, float* u, const float* K, float* y, const float* C) {
    /*
     * Compute the vector A_vec = A*x
     */
    float A_vec[adim*1];
    memset(A_vec, 0, adim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*) A, x, A_vec, adim, adim, 1);

    /*
     * Compute the vector B_vec = B*u
     */
    float B_vec[adim*1];
    memset(B_vec, 0, adim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*) B, u, B_vec, adim, rdim, 1);

    /*
     * Compute the vector C_vec = C*x
     */
    float C_vec[ydim*1];
    memset(C_vec, 0, ydim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*) C, x, C_vec, ydim, adim, 1);

    /*
     * Compute the vector KC_vec = K*C_vec
     */
    float KC_vec[adim*1];
    memset(KC_vec, 0, adim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*) K, C_vec, KC_vec, adim, ydim, 1);

    /*
     * Compute the vector Ky_vec = K*y
     */
    float Ky_vec[adim*1];
    memset(Ky_vec, 0, adim*sizeof(float));
    mul((float*) K, y, Ky_vec, adim, ydim, 1);

    /*
     * Now add x = A_vec - KC_vec + B_vec + Ky_vec
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < adim; i++){
        *(x + i) = *(A_vec + i) - *(KC_vec + i) + *(B_vec + i) + *(Ky_vec + i);
    }

}

/*
 * C = A*B
 */
static void mul(float* A, float* B, float* C, int row_a, int column_a, int column_b) {

    // Data matrix
    float* data_a = A;
    float* data_b = B;

    for (int i = 0; i < row_a; i++) {
        // Then we go through every column of b
        for (int j = 0; j < column_b; j++) {
            data_a = &A[i * column_a];
            data_b = &B[j];

            *C = 0; // Reset
            // And we multiply rows from a with columns of b
            for (int k = 0; k < column_a; k++) {
                *C += *data_a * *data_b;
                data_a++;
                data_b += column_b;
            }
            C++; // ;)
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Print matrix or vector - Just for error check
 */
static void print(float* A, int row, int column) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%0.18f ", *(A++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Misra doesn't say you can't allocate memory.  Are the matlab functions you use Misra certified? Writing ASIL D compliant code isn't usually easy using manual memory allocation - but - dumping Matlab code here in hope to get an answer is probablly wasting your time. Ask (contract) whomever delivered the matlab module for a certificate. If you are the person writing the module, ask matllab. If they can't provide that cert, neither can you.

Comment: ... and if you're in the automotive business, there's usually a base tech type of  organisation available to provide guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I work on MATLAB Coder

1. There is a [configuration setting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/coder.codeconfig.html?searchHighlight=dynamicmemoryallocation&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to tell MATLAB Coder to generate code without using dynamically allocated memory or issue an error telling you why it can't do so.

   ```matlab
   cfg = coder.config('lib');
   cfg.DynamicMemoryAllocation = 'Off';
   codegen -config cfg ...
   ```
2. MATLAB Coder supports generating code with fixed-size arrays, variable-sized arrays, and dynamically allocated arrays. The various generated signature formats are shown in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html). For non-dynamically allocated variable-sized arrays, a common signature is something like: `foo(x_data[100], x_size[2])`
3. Yes, the generated code is generally portable and independent of MATLAB for the hardware you specify when generating code. The full list of available functions and classes supported for code generation is [listed here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-and-objects-supported-for-cc-code-generation.html). In a very small number of cases, the generated code needs to depend on libraries from MATLAB. Those cases will be called out in the documentation. Fundamental operations like `horzcat` and `vertcat` produce portable code that is independent of MATLAB.
4. Yes. For array outputs and MATLAB functions with multiple outputs, the generated code will return outputs by reference. It also supports passing an argument by reference in some cases when the corresponding MATLAB function has the [same variable as an input and output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/eliminate-redundant-copies-of-function-inputs.html): `function A = foo(A,B)` with a call like: `y = foo(y,z);` can produce something like `void foo(double A[100], const double B[20]);` where `A` is an input and output.

Comment: Great! One question more! How optimized is the C-code?

Comment: Many core computations optionally support using high-performance libraries and Embedded Coder gives the ability for other hardware-specific optimizations. I'd suggest getting a [trial](https://www.mathworks.com/campaigns/products/trials.html?prodcode=ME) and measuring for yourself.